# Converting Strings to JSON Convertable Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string, json

I am querying a database for results and trying to convert them into JSON encodable array where the key will act as the name of the pair and the value is the value. How would I do this in the following code below?

```
    foreach($results as $result) {
       foreach( $result as $key => $value ) {
        if ($key == 'D')
        {
            $trimmed = round($value, 4);
        }
            else
            {
                $trimmed = trim($value, "\n\r");
            }
            $array[$i] ="$key"."=>"."$trimmed"; 
       }
       $i = 0;
       $jret = json_encode($array);
       echo $jret;
    }
```

For example:

```
<?php
$object[0] = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);
$encoded_object = json_encode($object);
?>
```

output:

```
{"1": {"foo": "bar", "12": "true"}}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't return such output. Ever tried to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dunno what you need and why you *mimic* PHP code instead of using it, but may be

```
$array[] = array($key => $trimmed);
```

is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

with

```
$array[$i][$key] = $trimmed;
```

you could do

```
$return = json_encode($object, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

at the end